# xslt sort alphabetically attributes in row

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to sort alphabetically both elements and attributes inside elements on a xml file.

Just discovering XSLT:

**source.xml**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wgtPage projectType="project" rev="1">
   <object staticFile="opt/IMAGE.png"
           id="ZZZZZZZZZ"
           staticOptEnable="true"
           dataWndSize="0,70"
           downloadPrepDone="true"
           usedFonts="Siemens AD Sans"
           pageSize="1920,1080"
           class="PageWgt"
           pageName="PAGENAME"
           templateFile="PAEGEFILE.XML">
      <wgtStyle width="1920"
                height="1080"
                ver="040500548"
                fitToSize="1"
                x="0"
                y="0"
                v="04.05.00.548"/>
      <object mgrType="Page"
              id="_PageMLTextMgrWgt"
              mlFileName=""
              class="PageMLTextMgrWgt">
         <wgtStyle width="0" height="0" x="0" y="0"/>
         <langs curLangId="L1" defLangId="L1">
            <lang name="ITA"
                  defaultFont="ARIAL"
                  keypads=";;"
                  writingsystem="Any"
                  langId="L1"
                  langCode="it"
                  removable="false"/>
         </langs>
         <MLTexts>
            <MLText id="0" L1="A"/>
            <MLText id="1" L1="E "/>
            <MLText id="36" L1="D"/>
            <MLText id="37" L1="B"/>
         </MLTexts>
      </object>
      <object id="label11" class="LabelWgt">
         <wgtStyle wrapping="true"
                   width="247"
                   height="29"
                   font-bold="true"
                   keypad-type="None"
                   vert-align="middle"
                   font-sizepx="21"
                   font-color="rgb(255,215,0)"
                   font-size="16"
                   marker="true"
                   x="9"
                   y="28"
                   forcePaint="1"
                   cx="123.50"
                   cy="13.74"
                   font-family="Sans"/>
         <links>
            <lang textid="0" class="MLTextLink"/>
         </links>
      </object>
      <links>
         <lang textid="36" class="MLTextLink"/>
      </links>
   </object>
   <object id="GroupWgt5.label1" class="LabelWgt">
      <wgtStyle y="877"
                font-size="22"
                height="76"
                frameSize="0"
                vert-align="middle"
                font-family="ARIAL"
                x="1122"
                alignment="center"
                forcePaint="25"
                wgtStaticOpt="dynamic"
                frameColor="rgb(200,200,200)"
                font-color="rgb(255,255,255)"
                cy="34.20"
                frameFill="rgb(102,102,102)"
                frame="true"
                keypad-type="None"
                font-sizepx="29"
                wrapping="true"
                width="210"
                cx="107.56"/>
      <dataLinks>
         <dataLink tag="THISISATAG"
                   tagType="boolean"
                   widgetType="Project"
                   attribute="frameFill"
                   sourceType="Tag"
                   tagIndex="-1"
                   dataSource="_TagMgr"
                   class="TagMgrWgt"
                   readWrite="R">
            <xForms>
               <xForm name="ColorPaletteCustom"
                      ColorPaletteCustom="#707070;#009942"
                      class="ColorPaletteCustomXForm">
                  <value i="0">0</value>
                  <value i="1">1</value>
               </xForm>
            </xForms>
         </dataLink>
      </dataLinks>
      <links>
         <lang textid="37" class="MLTextLink"/>
      </links>
   </object>
   <object id="MAINOBJ@$GroupSubscrWgt@$0" class="GroupSubscribeWgt">
      <wgtStyle width="0" height="0" x="0" y="0"/>
   </object>
</wgtPage>
```

**xslt template**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="Just discovering XSLT,yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="text"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFuiXXX

Comment: What is your exact question, what is the desired result? In what way does your code fail?

Comment: Desired result: keep alphabetical order this to allow versioning of xml files within git repository. If you edit sorting without editing values git will take it as a modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you cannot sort attributes, because the order of attributes is by [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags) insignificant. And you certainly cannot sort attributes by an `id` attribute which they don't (and cannot) have.

Still, in practice most - if not all - processors will obey a properly constructed command to sort attributes. Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <parent b="yy" c="zz" a="xx">
        <child id="2">Two</child>
        <child id="3">Three</child>
        <child id="1">One</child>
    </parent>
    <parent b="yyy" c="zzz" a="xxx">
        <child id="2">Two</child>
        <child id="3">Three</child>
        <child id="1">One</child>
    </parent>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- sort attributes by their name -->
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- sort child nodes by their id attribute -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
   <parent a="xx" b="yy" c="zz">
      <child id="1">One</child>
      <child id="2">Two</child>
      <child id="3">Three</child>
   </parent>
   <parent a="xxx" b="yyy" c="zzz">
      <child id="1">One</child>
      <child id="2">Two</child>
      <child id="3">Three</child>
   </parent>
</input>
```

---

(*) Tested with libxslt, Xalan 2.7.2, Saxon 6.5, MS XslCompiledTransform, MSXML6, Transformiix, Saxon 10.6.